# Getting error "File ... couldn’t be opened because there is no such file" for exising file

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-fetch-blob

I'm using [rn-fetch-blob](https://github.com/wkh237/react-native-fetch-blob) 0.10.8 with RN 0.49 on iOS with iPhone 6 Simulator.

I'm using the react-native-image-resizer module to resize an image and then I use react-native-fetch-blob to move that image to the right location. However, when doing so I'm getting the error:

> The file “6492238E-AAAC-4DC6-90F3-AFAB7225DBD5.jpg” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file.

Before doing the copy, I'm printing the source and destination to the console:

> "Moving file:///Users/laurent/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/3AF6C788-B6ED-41DD-85F0-32D719DB0DBE/data/Containers/Data/Application/A401D341-9C60-4AA3-8D8F-69207A8C9454/Library/Caches/6492238E-AAAC-4DC6-90F3-AFAB7225DBD5.jpg => /Users/laurent/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/3AF6C788-B6ED-41DD-85F0-32D719DB0DBE/data/Containers/Data/Application/A401D341-9C60-4AA3-8D8F-69207A8C9454/Documents/testing.jpg"

I can verify that the path `//Users/laurent/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/3AF6C788-B6ED-41DD-85F0-32D719DB0DBE/data/Containers/Data/Application/A401D341-9C60-4AA3-8D8F-69207A8C9454/Library/Caches/6492238E-AAAC-4DC6-90F3-AFAB7225DBD5.jpg` exist as I can open it in Finder. However for some reason rn-fetch-blob doesn't find it.

Any idea what could be the issue?

For information this the code I'm using:

```
const resizedImage = await ImageResizer.createResizedImage(localFilePath, dimensions.width, dimensions.height, format, 85);
const resizedImagePath = resizedImage.uri;
console.info('Moving ' + resizedImagePath + ' => ' + targetPath);
await RNFetchBlob.fs.cp(resizedImagePath, targetPath); // Throws error
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that this path isn't reachable from JavaScript, you need first save it to a valid place, like application `temp` folder, and then pass the `temp` folder URL.
This is how you save to `temp` folder on iOS:

```
+(NSURL*)saveToTmpFolder:(NSData*)data {
    NSString *temporaryFileName = [NSProcessInfo processInfo].globallyUniqueString;
    NSString *temporaryFilePath = [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:[temporaryFileName stringByAppendingPathExtension:@"jpg"]];
    NSURL *temporaryFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:temporaryFilePath];

    NSError *error = nil;
    [data writeToURL:temporaryFileURL options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:&error];

    if ( error ) {
        //NSLog( @"Error occured while writing image data to a temporary file: %@", error );
    }
    else {
        //NSLog(@"Image Saved - YOU ROCK!");
    }
    return temporaryFileURL;
}
```

Or if you wan JavaScript API, [react-native-fs](https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs) is a great solution.

Comment: Yes that was it, I have replaced `RNFetchBlob.fs.cp(source, target)` by `RNFS.copyFile(source, target)` and it worked. I don't understand though why one work and the other doesn't since both are native modules? Or is a bug in RNFetchBlob? Either way thank you for pointing me in the right direction.